# Pipewire virtual device (audio source) combining monitoring default sound output device and default capturing device

Tags: audio, pipewire

Is it possible to create pipewire virtual audio source device which would combine (mix) sound monitoring from current default audio device (whatever it is) and default capturing device?
Could you please help me to create user config to do it?

And the second virtual device which would mix left and right stereo channels from default capturing device and send them to e.g. right channel, and mix all channels from default output device and send them to left channel. That is, don't mix sound from capturing and output device, but send them to right and left stereo channels simultaneously.

Seems like that may be a good starting point

https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/wikis/Virtual-Devices#combine-source-selected-channels-and-sources

but I have no idea how to modify it to meet the requirements above